# How to clear Cache of Navigation Cache Mode in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, caching, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to clear the Navigation Cache where  NavigationCacheMode is set to

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

But I need cache for some page navigation like while uploading photo in a post,  I need to go to file uploader page then return back to my post. But when I post something and come again to post another post the data which I returned before remains the same.

Is there anyway I can reset the cache to default for selected page navigation only?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227506):

> If you change the value of `NavigationCacheMode` from `Required` or `Enabled` to `Disabled`, the page is flushed from the cache.

As I understood:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

when you want to clear the cache and then set it back to

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled / Required;
```

when you want to re-enable it.